# perl - extract list of strings

Tags: regex, linux, perl, unix, grep

dummy.txt contains:

```
gflkgWXYZ_123jfdknABC_8723879bfdkh873ABC_456jhb
gflkUI_12643jfdknABC_bfdk873WXYZ_7848jhb
ABC_1121fABC_22462
WXYZ_33273
3ABC_888
```

I'm trying to match all of these WXYZ_(optionally numbers) ie WXYZ_23 and ABC_(optionally numbers). ie ABC_

What perl script (i'm running on solaris with no GNU) would allow me to produce the following output file?

```
WXYZ_123
ABC_8723879
ABC_456
ABC_
WXYZ_7848
ABC_1121
ABC_22462
WXYZ_33273
ABC_888
```

Comment: Can such strings be across new lines? Also I understand you want only WXYZ or ABC, or any all-caps three-letters is ok?

Comment: looking for just WXYZ or ABC not other string combos

Answer (score 4):

use this regular expression `((ABC)|(WXYZ))_\d*`

Comment: So `perl -pe '$_=join"\n",/((?:ABC|WXYZ)_\d*)/g,""'` would be the final script, just to complete the answer.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
perl -ne '
    push @list, $1 while m/((?:WXYZ|ABC)_\d*)/g;
    END { 
        printf qq|%s\n|, join qq|\n|, @list;
    }
' infile
```

Output:

```
WXYZ_123                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ABC_8723879                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
ABC_456                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
ABC_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
WXYZ_7848                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ABC_1121                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ABC_22462                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
WXYZ_33273                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ABC_888
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it need to be Perl?

```
egrep -o '(WXYZ|ABC)_[0-9]*' dummy.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

burning_LEGION has it right, though it's easier to do the alternation inside of non-capturing parentheses.  You also have to collect the results somehow.  Assuming you only want ABC_ or WXYZ_ and not anything else, try this short program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @matches;
open(FILE, '<', "dummy.txt") or die "Failed to open dummy.txt - $!\n";
foreach (<FILE>) {
    1 while /((?:ABC|WXYZ)_\d*)/g && push(@matches, $1);
}
close(FILE) or die "Failed to close dummy.txt - $!\n";

open(OUTPUT, '>', "output.txt") or die "Failed to open output.txt - $!\n";
print OUTPUT join("\n", @matches);
close(OUTPUT) or die "Failed to close output.txt - $!\n";

exit 0;
```

> $cat output.txt
>   WXYZ_123
>   ABC_8723879
>   ABC_456
>   ABC_
>   WXYZ_7848
>   ABC_1121
>   ABC_22462
>   WXYZ_33273
>   ABC_888